# IF statement in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, if-statement

I have a table with feed for our system

it's look like this:

`id | owner_id | user_id | feed_type_id | object_id | created_at | updated_at`

`feed_type_id` - represent type of object that is stored in different table (article or job_post)

`object_id` is the object ID itself, but I don't have a clue if this object is still active. So I have get all active id for different type of object, but when
I am trying to build query with IF statement something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM feeds 
WHERE "owner_id" in (2, 4, 1356) 
  AND object_id IN ( IF `feed_type_id` = 1 THEN (2,3,23,33) ELSE (4,5,77,33) end if)
```

it's not working.

Can someone give me an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IF` statements are not part of the SQL language, but part of the [procedural language](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS). As such, you can't use them directly in queries.

The query you're looking for is something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM feeds 
WHERE 
    "owner_id" in (2, 4, 1356) AND 
    (
        ("feed_type_id" = 1 AND "object_id" IN (2, 3, 23, 33)) OR
        ("feed_type_id" != 1 AND "object_id" IN (4, 5, 77, 33))
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html) expression like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM feeds 
WHERE "owner_id" IN (2, 4, 1356) 
AND object_id    IN (CASE 
                         WHEN "feed_type_id" = 1 THEN (2,3,23,33) 
                         ELSE (4,5,77,33) 
                     END)
```

Comment: Documentation: [Conditional Expressions in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-conditional.html)